# Indexed Map Thread

Tags: list-manipulation, map

I'm attempting to MapThread a function of two lists that requires the index of the list values. For example,

```
MapThread[#1*i+#2*j&,{{a,b,c},{e,f,g}}]
```

Where #1 represents the value from list 1, #2 the value from list 2, i the index of list 1, and j the index of list 2. The expected output is

```
{a+e,2b+2f,3c+3g}
```

This would presumably be accomplished by an "IndexedMapThread" function, but I'm not sure something like that exists in Mathematica currently.

Any suggestions on how to do this simply?

Answer (score 10):

Update:

```
ClearAll[imtF]
imtF[foo_] := Module[{i = 1}, foo[#, i++] & /@ Transpose@#] &
```

Examples:

```
imtF[#2 (Plus @@ #) &][{{a, b, c}, {e, f, g}}]
(* {a + e, 2 (b + f), 3 (c + g)} *)

xx = {{a, b, c}, {e, f, g}, {x, y, z}};
imtF[#2 (Plus @@ #) &][xx]
(* {a + e + x, 2 (b + f + y), 3 (c + g + z)} *)

imtF[Plus @@ Times@## &][xx]
(* {a + e + x, 2 b + 2 f + 2 y, 3 c + 3 g + 3 z} *)

fn[x_, i_] := #*i + #2*i + #3^i & @@ x (*Mr.W's example modified *)
imtF[fn][xx]
(* {a + e + x, 2 b + 2 f + y^2, 3 c + 3 g + z^3} *)
```

---

```
Range[Length@#] Thread@+## &[{a, b, c}, {e, f, g}]
MapIndexed[# #2[[1]] &, Thread[Plus[##]]] &[{a, b, c}, {e, f, g}]
MapIndexed[# #2[[1]] &, +## & @@@ ({##}\[Transpose])] &[{a, b, c}, {e, f, g}]
MapIndexed[+(## & @@ # ) #2[[1]] &, #\[Transpose]] &@{{a, b, c}, {e, f, g}}
```

all give

```
(* {a + e, 2 (b + f), 3 (c + g)} *)
```

Comment: aaahh, penguins working on the same q/a as you again, tell me which is neater ?

Comment: It seems to me than none of this is general.  By my reading the OP is not asking merely for a particular mathematical operation but rather a general method of application.

Comment: @penguin77 it is a small world :)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, good point, thank you. Updated with something that works with general two-arg functions.

Comment: Now you get my vote. :-)

Comment: @kguler, incredible rich answer to a small question. Great thanks! +1. By the way you win on performance, see my "update for fun".

Comment: @penguin77, thank you. Interesting negative correlation b/w `StringLength` and speed:)

Answer (score 8):

You may consider this

```
MapIndexed[Times, #] & /@ {{a, b, c}, {e, f, g}}  // Plus @@ # & 

(* {{a + e}, {2 b + 2 f}, {3 c + 3 g}} *)
```

`MapIndexed` applies a function (in your example `Times` to all elements of the list giving part specification (in your example `i` respectively `j`) as the second argument. The two resulting lists are then added in the postfix expression.

You may flatten to get

```
 % //Flatten 
(* {a + e, 2 b + 2 f, 3 c + 3 g} *)
```

**Update for fun.**
 I know it's not part of q/a. However the numerous different answers  are well suited for gaining insight on performance. 
Here the results with a data set `{Range @ 10^6, Range @ 10^6}`. (kguler's examples correspond to the non updated version posted).
kguler's `Range[Length@#] Thread@+## &[*dataset*]` is about **45 times faster** than the slowest solution proposed. This is simply amazing and gives ground for analyzing what makes one approach faster than another.

[image]

PS: Interested in  `ColorFunction -> AntarcticColor` ? Here the "receipt": 
`AntarcticColor[ z_ ] := RGBColor[z/2, 1 - z, 1];`

PS,PS: hmmm, Wizards waddling behind penguins ?!

Comment: ++1 for  `AntarcticColor`:)

Answer (score 5):

At face value there is this solution:

```
IndexedMapThread[list1_,list2_] := 
  MapThread[(#1*#3+#2*#4 &),{list1,list2,Range@Length@list1,Range@Length@list2}]

IndexedMapThread[{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}]
  (* {a + d, 2 b + 2 e, 3 c + 3 f} *)
```

Comment: This is throwing an error at me "MapThread called with 5 arguments

Comment: Crap, sorry, I forgot to wrap the lists and ranges into curly braces. Fixed. And it still got upvoted :D, I guess everybody just looked at the code, thought "seems legit" and didn't test it :-)

Comment: Incidentally one could assume that the lists are the same length and use:  `MapThread[(#1*#3+#2*#4 &),{list1,list2, #, #}] & @ Range @ Length @ list1` or the equivalent `With`.

Comment: I'm a bit concerned about possible conflicts of `#1` and `#` in this code snippet (what if it substitutes the range into the first argument of `MapThread`? I don't have Mathematica handy right now to check), but following the gist of your comment I'd prefer then `MapThread[(#3(#1+#2)&),{list1,list2,#}] & @ Range @ Length @ list1`. No need to assume anything, as `MapThread` will throw an error if the lists are not of the same length anyway.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP, it also already happened to me. HINT: Always copy immediately the posted code back into Notebook and evaluate, for cross-checking. Making it a good habit.

Comment: @penguin77 I did and corrected it in Mathematica, but forgot to do so in my answer and went shopping. Sorry :-)

Comment: @penguin77 & LL I can't count how many times I've copied the wrong code section into an answer.  I suppose it indicates a failure in my developmental methods but I often have similar looking chucks of code for testing different methods and it's often not until the final version that I add proper localization, etc.

Answer (score 5):

Since it would seem that your index values *i* and *j* will always be the same you need only to [`Transpose`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose.html) your input and use [`MapIndexed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapIndexed.html):

```
MapIndexed[
  #[[1]]*#2[[1]] + #[[2]]*#2[[1]] &,
  {{a, b, c}, {e, f, g}}\[Transpose]
]
```

> ```
> {a + e, 2 b + 2 f, 3 c + 3 g}
> ```

Here `#[[1]]` is the first element, `#[[2]]` is the second element, and `#2[[1]]` is the (universal) index.

---

To make this easier to use consider rewriting your function as follows:

```
fn[x_, {i_}] := #*i + #2*i + #3^i & @@ x

MapIndexed[fn, {{a, b, c}, {e, f, g}, {x, y, z}}\[Transpose]]
```

> ```
> {a + e + x, 2 b + 2 f + y^2, 3 c + 3 g + z^3}
> ```

A third parameter is included for illustration.  `i` represents the universal index.

Answer (score 3):

Here is definition for `indexedMapThread` that works for any number of lists so long as they are all equal in length.

```
indexedMapThread[args : {_List ..}] :=
 Module[{sizes = Length /@ args, scalars},
  If[Not[Equal @@ sizes], Return[$Failed]];
  scalars = Range@sizes[[1]];
  Expand @ Flatten @ Thread[{#1 Plus[##2]}&[scalars, Sequence @@ args]]]

indexedMapThread @ {{a, b, c}}
```

> ```
> {a, 2 b, 3 c}
> ```

```
indexedMapThread @ {{a, b, c}, {e, f, g}}
```

> ```
> {a + e, 2 b + 2 f, 3 c + 3 g}
> ```

```
indexedMapThread @ {{a, b, c}, {e, f, g}, {h, i, j}}
```

> ```
> {a + e + h, 2 b + 2 f + 2 i, 3 c + 3 g + 3 j}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {{a, b, c}, {e, f, g}};
```

If the length of the list elements is known:

```
Transpose[list] * Range[3] // MapApply[Plus]
```

{a + e, 2 b + 2 f, 3 c + 3 g}

Otherwise

```
Transpose[list] * Range[Length @ First @ list] // MapApply[Plus]
```

{a + e, 2 b + 2 f, 3 c + 3 g}

Answer (score 2):

Using `MapThread`:

```
F = MapThread[Total@*Times, {Transpose@#, Range[Last@Dimensions@#]}] &;

F@{{a, b, c}, {e, f, g}} // RepeatedTiming

(*{0.0000308525, {a + e, 2 b + 2 f, 3 c + 3 g}}*)
```

Also, using `MapIndexed`:

```
F = MapIndexed[Total[#1*#2[[1]]] &, Transpose@#] &;

F@{{a, b, c}, {e, f, g}} // RepeatedTiming

(*{0.0000305187, {a + e, 2 b + 2 f, 3 c + 3 g}}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in a comment by @eldo (and thanks!)

```
MapThread[Plus,{{a,b,c},{e,f,g}}] Range[3]//Expand

(* {a+e,2 b+2 f,3 c+3 g} *)
```

**Also**

```
MapThread[Plus]@MapIndexed[#2[[2]]  #1&,{{a,b,c},{e,f,g}},{2}]

(* {a+e,2 b+2 f,3 c+3 g} *)
```

**Original Answer**

```
MapThread[Plus[#1,#2] &,{{a,b,c},{e,f,g}}] Range[3]//Expand

(* {a+e,2 b+2 f,3 c+3 g} *)
```

Comment: +1. but `MapThread[Plus, {{a, b, c}, {e, f, g}}] * Range[3]` would be sufficient

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you'd need differing variable names, since the index would always be same, but, that aside:

```
imt[f_, l_, v_] := Module[Evaluate@v, MapThread[(v = ConstantArray[#3, Length@v]; f) &, 
                    Append[l, Range@Length@l[[1]]]]];
```

Your example (note last entry is names of variables to be realized):

```
imt[#1*i + #2*j, {{a, b, c}, {e, f, g}}, {i, j}]
(* {a + e, 2 b + 2 f, 3 c + 3 g} *)
```